# "Database is locked" Even though I did call database.close()

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm simply trying to store data via SQLite. I'm letting the user create their own list.

The values the list stores are String, int, and ArrayList (currently not using that at the moment).

**What I'm dealing with:**

After I finished setting up SQLite and ran my program I got this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
```

So, after doing some research, *the problem happened as a result of the database not closing.* However, here's the thing:

```
private Context mContext;
private EasyListSQLiteHelper mEasyListSQLiteHelper;

public EasyListDataSource(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mEasyListSQLiteHelper = new EasyListSQLiteHelper(context);
}

private SQLiteDatabase open() {
    return mEasyListSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

private void close(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.close();
}

public ArrayList<ListItem> read() {
    ArrayList<ListItem> listItems = readList();
    return listItems;
}

public ArrayList<ListItem> readList() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = open();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_TABLE,
            new String[] {EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_NAME, BaseColumns._ID, EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_CHECKED},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    ArrayList<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem(getIntFromColumnName(cursor, BaseColumns._ID),
                    getStringFromColumnName(cursor, EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_NAME),
                    getIntFromColumnName(cursor, EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_CHECKED),
                    null);
            list.add(listItem);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    close(database);
    return list;
}

private int getIntFromColumnName(Cursor cursor, String columnName) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
    return cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
}

private String getStringFromColumnName(Cursor cursor, String columnName) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
    return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
}

public void create(ListItem item) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = open();
    database.beginTransaction();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_NAME, item.getListName());
    contentValues.put(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_CHECKED, item.getImportant());
    database.insert(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_TABLE, null, contentValues);

    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.close();
    close(database);
}
```

As you can see, I *did* close the database. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here then. This is not the only place I'm getting the error however (commented the lines where I'm getting errors):

DataSource:

```
private Context mContext;
private EasyListSQLiteHelper mEasyListSQLiteHelper;

public EasyListDataSource(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mEasyListSQLiteHelper = new EasyListSQLiteHelper(context);
}

private SQLiteDatabase open() {
    // return mEasyListSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

private void close(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.close();
}

public ArrayList<ListItem> read() {
    ArrayList<ListItem> listItems = readList();
    return listItems;
}

public ArrayList<ListItem> readList() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = open();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_TABLE,
            new String[] {EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_NAME, BaseColumns._ID, EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_CHECKED},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    ArrayList<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem(getIntFromColumnName(cursor, BaseColumns._ID),
                    getStringFromColumnName(cursor, EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_NAME),
                    getIntFromColumnName(cursor, EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_CHECKED),
                    null);
            list.add(listItem);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    close(database);
    return list;
}

private int getIntFromColumnName(Cursor cursor, String columnName) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
    return cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
}

private String getStringFromColumnName(Cursor cursor, String columnName) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
    return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
}

public void create(ListItem item) {
    // SQLiteDatabase database = open();
    database.beginTransaction();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_NAME, item.getListName());
    contentValues.put(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_CHECKED, item.getImportant());
    database.insert(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_TABLE, null, contentValues);

    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.close();
    close(database);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lists);

    // Initialize variables...
    mAddListImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addListImageView);
    mColorImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.colorImageView);
    mRecyclerViewLists = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
    mEmptyListTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyListTextView);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_lists);
    mListList = new ArrayList<>();
    mOpenDeleteDialogListClickListener = this;
    mRemoveListClickListener = this;
}

// Is the adapter empty?
private void checkAdapterIsEmpty() {
    if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
        mEmptyListTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mEmptyListTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

// Setup RecyclerView...
protected void RecyclerViewSetup() {
    mAdapter = new ListsAdapter(mOpenDeleteDialogListClickListener, mListList);
    mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            checkAdapterIsEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition, toPosition, itemCount);
        }
    });

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerViewLists.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerViewLists.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerViewLists.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    checkAdapterIsEmpty();
}

// Initializing interfaces...
@Override
public void createListClickListener(View v, String string) {
    mListItem = new ListItem();
    mListItem.setListName(string);
    mListList.add(mListItem);
    mRecyclerViewLists.scrollToPosition(mListList.size() - 1);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // saveList();
    Toast.makeText(ListsActivity.this, "\"" + mListItem.getListName() + "\"" + " has been created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void saveList() {
    EasyListDataSource easyListDataSource = new EasyListDataSource(this);
    // easyListDataSource.create(mListItem);
}
```

NewItemDialogFragment:

```
public interface CreateListClickListener {
    void createListClickListener(View v, String string);
}

public void setCreateListClickListener(CreateListClickListener createListClickListener) {
    mCreateListClickListener = createListClickListener;
}

public NewListDialogFragment() {}

private EditText mListEditText;
private TextView mAcceptListTextView;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private CreateListClickListener mCreateListClickListener;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = getActivity();

    // Creating the builder...
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View dialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_list_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    // Initialize variables...
    mListEditText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listEditText);
    mAcceptListTextView = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.acceptListTextView);
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.NewListLayout);

    // Creating the dialog...
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    // OnClickListeners...
    mAcceptListTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String item = mListEditText.getText().toString();
            if (item.equals("") || item.startsWith(" ")) {
                String message = "Please fill in the empty field.";
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // mCreateListClickListener.createListClickListener(view, item);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create method you need to end your transaction to unblock the database:

```js
public void create(ListItem item) {
    // SQLiteDatabase database = open();
    database.beginTransaction();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_NAME, item.getListName());
    contentValues.put(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_CHECKED, item.getImportant());
    database.insert(EasyListSQLiteHelper.LISTS_TABLE, null, contentValues);

    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    database.close();
    close(database);
}
```